# With Semantic-UI, how to center align form fields?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm working to build a form using Semantic-UI-React: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form

The current form's code and output can be seen below via the image. I can't figure out, how to I center align the form fields? I don't want the form fields to take up the entire width of the page which is why the fields have a class of "ten wide"... How can I center align the form fields?

[image]

```html
<form class="RaterInviteForm ui form">
   <div class="ui form">
      <div class="fields">
         <div class="ten wide field">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="ui input"><input type="text" name="emails[0]" value="" placeholder="name@example.com"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
         <div class="ten wide field">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="ui input"><input type="text" name="emails[1]" value="" placeholder="name@example.com"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
         <div class="ten wide field">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="ui input"><input type="text" name="emails[2]" value="" placeholder="name@example.com"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field"><a href="true">Add Email</a></div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="ui primary button float-right">Send Invitations</button><button class="ui grey basic button">Skip For Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<Grid.Row centered>`:

```
<Container>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Row centered>
            <Grid.Column width={6}>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input label="Email Address" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input label="Email Address" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input label="Email Address" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    </Form.Field>
                </Form>
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
</Container>
```